# How do I Restrict Access to My Static Website on Amazon S3 by asking for Credentials

Tags: authentication, amazon-s3, authorization

I'm hosting a Static Website on AmazonS3 (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html).

However, I wish to grant access to my page ONLY by authorizing and subsequently authenticating users.

What services are available (Heroku, etc.,) that allows me to do that? I would like the option of having login using their social networking IDs (facebook, twitter, etc.,).

Thanks for your direction on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scenario you describe cannot be achieved purely via Amazon S3.

While there is security available in Amazon S3, it uses either:

- AWS credentials (that should not be issued to your application users), or
- [Pre-Signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) that grant users temporary access to objects in Amazon S3 (but they need to be generated by an application)

You will need an **application** that accepts their login and verifies the level of access they are permitted. The application can then generate pre-signed URLs to grant access to specific objects in Amazon S3. The traditional way to provide such an application is on a **web server running on Amazon EC2**. (An alternative is to use [Serverless code](http://docs.serverless.com/docs). Here is an [example](https://serverlesscode.com/post/david-guetta-online-recording-with-lambda/))

You could use [Web Identity Federation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_oidc.html) to authenticate users via Facebook, Google and Amazon, as part of the above process.

Comment: thanks for your note. Now, I have a few options to study and identify what works for me. Will update this ticket based on what I find out.