# Trying to make a webpage accessible only after re-direction from a particular url in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a webpage deployed from S3 bucket and the url for it is 
***http://webpage.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/***

For this, I have created another login page and the url for the login page is ***http://login.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/***. 
This works fine because I am pointing the login page to be opened first and when users type in their credentials, the webpage will be displayed.

However, I am able to access the webpage directly when I enter the webpage url in the browser which is not the way I want it to be.

Can I redirect the users to login page when the webpage url is typed in the browser? I want all the users to be redirected to the login page first even when they type in the webpage URL.

Could someone help me out in achieving this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I Restrict Access to My Static Website on Amazon S3 by asking for Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35027961/how-do-i-restrict-access-to-my-static-website-on-amazon-s3-by-asking-for-credent)

Comment: Hi, Vorsprung. Thank u very much for the reply. As of now, I have integrated okta with AWS and I am able to access the webpage by entering the credentials. After entering the credentials,if they are correct, the url is getting redirected to my webpage. But, there is another scenario where I am able to access the webpage by directly entering the webpage URL which is not what I want. The link u provided is discussing the ways to authenticate but that is not issue as I have added the OKTA authentication layer. Hope i understood ur point clearly. Please correct me if wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The presigned url sets up a special url that includes credentials for a accesskey/secretaccesskey pair.

Here is a python boto3 example that does this http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3.html#generating-presigned-urls

The presigned url is associated with a user.  The user should be listed as a principle in the bucket policy

See this AWS resource about principles in bucket policy http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-bucket-user-policy-specifying-principal-intro.html

Your problem is (I assume) that there is a bucket policy principle of * set so that all users, validated or not, are allowed into the bucket